# Using Imageresizer Watermark plugin to write text: Centered, width and line feeds

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm trying to use the watermark plugin to write text on images for my project. Right now I'm trying to find out how to set a "width" for a writing box so I can get automatic line returns. Is there a way to do this with the watermark plugin?

Also I'm trying to see if I can get a "text-align: center" effect when I'm writing my text (possibliy in relation to that set width), how could I get that setup?

I'm thinking that the alternative to this would be to have code driven line returns and centering, but this would mean that I would have to count the width of my characters and this seems like a world of pain hehe

Here is a code sample that shows what I'm doing (this currently works):

```
var c = Config.Current; 
var wp = c.Plugins.Get<WatermarkPlugin>();

var t = new TextLayer(); 
t.Text = panty.Message; 
t.TextColor = (System.Drawing.Color) color; 
t.Font = fonts[myFunObject.Font]; 
t.FontSize = fontSize[myFunObject.LogoPosition];

t.Left = new DistanceUnit(5, DistanceUnit.Units.Pixels); 
t.Top = new DistanceUnit(5, DistanceUnit.Units.Pixels);

wp.NamedWatermarks["myFunObjectMessage"] = new Layer[] { t };
```

EDIT: I also have to mention that the text I'm writing is user submitted so it's different everytime. If you want a similar case, think about thos funny cat images with funny text captions on them. This project is quite similar to that. (Minus the cats)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Might want to remove the asp.net-mvc-4 tag if the question doesn't have anything to do with it specifically.

Comment: So you're essentially looking for auto-wrap given a width and font size?

Comment: @asymptoticFault You're right! (Project is MVC4, but tag-wise it's not relevant)

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Essentially yeah and with that width, I'll want that text centered also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, System.Drawing (and therefore the current version of Watermark) are very primitive about line wrapping.

As you mentioned, you can do hacky stuff with character counting and separate MeasureString calls with loops, but the results are only barely acceptable.

You may try to fork the Watermark source code and hack support for your use case. I don't see a way to improve Watermark in a generic way without replacing the underlying graphics engine first (which may happen anyway).

System.Drawing has unsurpassed image resampling quality. Text wrapping, though, it kind of stinks at.

Comment: In another project, I've minimized the impact of the wrapping issue by splitting into different fields for user text entry and I use the centering options locationLayerC.Align = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;